# How can I retrieve the classpath string from my Eclipse project that uses Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classpath, m2e

How can I retrieve the classpath string from my Eclipse project that uses Maven?  In eclipse , I have more than 100 .jar files imported via Maven and refrences as a library called "Maven Dependencies".   How can I retrieve the "effective" classpath in the form of a string in my project?

The .classpath file does not reveal this.

Comment: Is this just a curiosity or what are you trying to achieve once you have this classpath?

Comment: I wan't to use the classpath string to launch the project from a script.

Comment: It's a very good question, the only way I can think of to approach this is to develop or modify an eclipse plug in.

Comment: @djangofan What kind of script? For end-users or developers (which use Maven)?

Comment: @Puce - I want to execute from a raw command line without having to do the tedious work of manually assembling my classpath.   My question is not about Maven: I have that covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the java development toolkit (JDT) in Eclipse.  The class JavaCore in the org.eclipse.jdt.core plugin can take a reference to your java project (an IProject) and return an IJavaProject which adds the behavior of knowing stuff about the classpath.  Maven provides a classpath container that should also collaborate with the IJavaProject to answer back the actual source folders and jars on the classpath.  Can't provide with any more info off the top of my head, but I think this approach is your only hope.

Unless you write an eclipse plugin that extends the maven plugin.  Documentation is sketchy at best, but in theory you can write an extension that is asked to tweak the contents of the maven container in your project's class path. If at that time you were to cache information about the container contents off to your plugin's state folder, you'd be able to reference it when the user wants you to invoke your script. This extension would be invoked whenever maven is asked to update project configuration or dependencies.

Comment: Ok, I have seen answers similar to this one on this forum.  I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to execute that script yourself and you have Maven installed. I guess the easiest way to run your application in this case is to use the Maven Exec Plugin:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

(I'm usually using the exec:exec goal to run the application in its own process.)

**Edit:**

Otherwise have a look at the Maven Dependency Plugin to prepare the classpath if you don't want to use the Maven Exec Plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/